# The Necessity Of Private Class Fields

Tags: oop

If you have a class with just contents like:

```
Public Class bertha
    Private x As Integer
    ' more fields here ...

    Public Property xVal() As Integer
        Get
            Return x
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            x = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ' more simple properties here
End Class
```

Is there any reason not to use

```
Public Class bertha
    Public x As Integer
    ' more fields here ...
End Class
```

Now, this is a question on class philosophy, not the easiest way to use x.

If the class's variables will not be validated, and will not be processed, what is the advantage(s) of using access only through properties, rather than just making the field(s) Public?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is that subclasses would be able to add validation and/or processing.

Comment: If this is only ever going to be used to hold a slate of values, is there any advantage to interfacing through properties?

Comment: If you could guarantee that restriction, probably not.  But you gain a lot of flexibility accessing through properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/535275